# opening worksheet in background

Tags: excel, vba

here's the process that i am running from a macro:

1. i open a worksheet
2. i add data to the worksheet
3. i save it
4. i close it

and i repeat the steps: 1, 2, 3... etc. (when i say I, i mean the stupid macro)

is it possible to open the worksheet in the background so that the user doesnt actually see that the worksheet is being opened?

Comment: Please show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Application.ScreenUpdating`. Set it to false before opening the worksheet, add the data and set it back to true afterwards.

Comment: that does not apply to this case

Comment: how do i pronounce your name franky?

Comment: Well, I can try - fran-tee-sac zee-a-chick

Comment: Now tell me how do I pronounce the name of yours :)

Comment: you pronounce like this: ZZUUUUUkay-Chi-ka-ka-moo

Comment: That's how it is written in our language (slovak)

Comment: well thanks for talking to me anyway, im going to mark this correct even though it's terribly wrong because i worded my question horribly, and thank you for being slovakian

Comment: Well, I'm lazy and anti-social too. I'm not fat though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use application.visible = false to hide an instance of an Excel Application object to the user.  ScreenUpdating will still show the workbook being opened in the taskbar.